# Using tape with create react app without ejecting

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

Is it possible to use `tape` to test `redux-saga` within `create-react-app` without ejecting?

It seems like it *might* be possible but I can't quite get things to work. My tape test is reported as:

```
 RUNS  src/tests/sagas/parserSaga.test.js
TAP version 13
 FAIL  src\tests\sagas\parserSaga.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_scheduler.js:95:22
          at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
          at <anonymous>
```

The bit that makes me hopeful is that `jest-cli` seemed to pickup `TAP version 13` so I presume it knows what tape tests are?